# java referencing not working

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I've been tasked to update some old software with new java 8 and new boss (we are now using jboss 6.4). I was able to fix a lot of think but now I facing a problem that goes against how I tought java was working.

we have in the code something like

```
    com.mda.ohs.od.service.RetrieveSoShippingInfoRemote service = getRetrieveSoShippingInfoRemoteHome().create();                        
output = (VoaRetrieveSoShippingInfo.Output) service.execute(input, output);

SoShippingInfoFormValueObject shippingInfoFormVoOutput = (SoShippingInfoFormValueObject ) output;
```

the service is correctly created and the output is correct. then we have

```
    com.mda.ohs.od.service.RetrieveSoSummaryRemote service = getRetrieveSoSummaryRemoteHome().create();
output = (VoaRetrieveSoShippingInfo.Output) service.execute(input, output);
```

output is correctly updated. Here is my issue: shippingInfoFormVoOutput should also be updated (as it was with the old java and jboss) but now it is not anymore and that create problem down the line.
Does anyone knows why the reference is not passed properly in my assignment

```
SoShippingInfoFormValueObject shippingInfoFormVoOutput = (SoShippingInfoFormValueObject ) output;
```

Is it a java configuration issue or an eclipse (my IDE) or jboss?

Thanks

Comment: Does the `VoaRetrieveSoShippingInfo.Output` extends `SoShippingInfoFormValueObject` ?

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee the "reference is passed properly". If, say, members of `output` are modified in `service.execute` then **iif** the value that's returned from `service.execute` is the *same object* they'll be reflected there. I'd suspect something further down the line than the code you've shown us here.

Comment: What do you call "updated"?

Comment: from what I've seen in the code VoaRetrieveSoShippingInfo.Output does not extends SoShippingInfoFormValueObject.

Comment: When I say updated I mean that output is assigned new value through the second service. shippingInfoFormVoOutput should also have these new values but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

After more studying of the code, I think like @Dave Newton said in his comment that the reference is passed properly from output to shippingInfoFormVoOutput the issue appears to be in `output = (VoaRetrieveSoShippingInfo.Output) service.execute(input, output);` 
The return value assignment to output doesn't use the same output reference that already exist but create a new one thus shippingInfoFormVoOutput and output now don't refer to the same object anymore. WHy does a new object is created for my output and not just update the already existing object?